# Sublime Text 3 AutoWrap breaks double quotes

Tags: sublimetext3

I installed a [package called Sublime Wrap Plus](https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus) to insert line break after wrapping text at 80 characters.

However, this breaks for example, the "long long long quotes" into

```
"long long long...
long quotes"
```

Which is a syntax error. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: 1. What language / tool are you working in? The syntax to append a string in the following line to the string on the current line is language specific. 2. Looking at the GitHub page at the link you supplied there are already a few people identifying this and similar issues and these appear to be unresolved for more than a year so it seems the package maintainer is not likely to provide a fix in the near future. 3. Given the above you should consider, instead, a beautifier or tidy or similar for the language you are interested in, possibly in tandem with a little script. Maybe?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using this plugin for writing code - it's mainly intended for text. You're likely to run into all sorts of problems like this when newlines are inserted blindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [README](https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus#using) is clear about this plugin detecting where to wrap paragraph text, not source code. Based on [their epilogue](https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus/#epilogue), you should open up an Issue for additional features.

Code wise, if you do want to add additional logic to the mix, its written in Python and [uses `if` statements like this one](https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus/blob/master/wrap_plus.py#L583) to parse the selected area as you see fit.